# Filebeat -> Kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

I am working with Filebeat, sending logs to Kafka. In some scenarios filebeat logs  show the following message:

```
Apr 17 20:14:10 appserver filebeat: 2018/04/18 00:14:10.378702 log.go:36: 
INFO producer/broker/[[0]] maximum request accumulated, waiting for space
```

I'd like to know, what is the reason this message appear. Is this an issue? What do I have to do to prevent if from appearing?

Comment: what is your Kafka setup look like, number of partitions per topic, number of brokers, replication ... etc. and what is your rate per second sending from FB to Kafka ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this github issue](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/issues/737#issuecomment-243937749) for the Kafka client library that Filebeat uses, it looks like Filebeat is producing at a greater rate than your Kafka broker can accept. 
You might want to scale out Kafka (more partitions & brokers), or change the [`required_acks` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html#_literal_required_acks_literal).